# How to use Caffe snapshot to recognize in practice?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a trained [caffe](/questions/tagged/caffe) snapshot, and now I want to use it to do some real recognition, i.e. input one or some files and get their NN outputs.

I want to do this in a python script, but shell batch is also fine.

Is there some documents or answers for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python script - take a look at this great ipython notebook:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb

For simple bash you could also use the cpp_classification tool, see more here:
http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/cpp_classification.html